# Receive only part of udp messages

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

I have a program that receives udp packets- that comprise 1 whole message in multicast.
Each udp has a header with id, its packet number in the message, total number of packets in message and some more properties to identify it.
I can see all the packets in wireshark on the receving computer, but when I check the packets that are being recevied in my code:
`var buffer= client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);` 
I see I'm only getting part of the packets: I get packets with "packet number in the message" 1,2,3..51
while "total number of packets" is 150.

Is there a reason for this? I can see the packets in Wireshark but not in my code..

Thank you!

Comment: You need to give us a little more context than `var buffer= client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);`.

Comment: This is not realy the point. this is jut the way I recevie the packets. some arrive, some not

Comment: Yes. That's UDP. It's unreliable. Now what do you expect from the SO community?